# Binding to HTTP images over HTTPS in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, ssl

I have an application that needs to be internet facing. It’s a Silverlight 4 front end running on top of WCF.

Right now I have two virtual directories on my internet facing server. One of the Silverlight app, the other for the WCF Service.

Am I gaining anything from hosting the Silverlight front end over SSL. I of course want to keep my WCF service under SSL but it seems to me like the Silverlight XAP might be ok over HTTP. They run fine over HTTPS but I’d like to move the XAP to run under HTTP because when  run under HTTPS the HTTP based images it tries to pull get denied because of cross scheme(I think).

Any security best practices for this?

Note:

To start I already read through this post about the clientaccesspolicy.xml and had no luck.
[Silverlight - Binding an image which is using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834040/silverlight-binding-an-image-which-is-using-https)

This is my file that still doesn't allow the HTTP images to render over HTTPS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
<cross-domain-access>
<policy>
  <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
    <domain uri="http://*"/>
    <domain uri="https://*" />
  </allow-from>
  <grant-to>
    <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
  </grant-to>
</policy>
</cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of various reasons why you might want to run your Silverlight app over HTTPS (for instance, if the XAP files contained information you didn't want to get sniffed), but they're not the normal scenario. It makes sense to me that you'd normally be fine with hosting the XAP files over HTTP instead of HTTPS.

With respect to accessing the images, are you actively specifying http instead of https? What happens if you just specify a relative location?